# crontab doesn't work after /etc/crontab is configured

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I added this line to the end of /etc/crontab file:

```
*       *       *       *      *      cp /etc /backups -R > /dev/null && tar -Jcf /backups/etc-`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M-\%S`.tar.xz /backups/etc > /dev/null && rm -rf /backups/etc > /dev/null
```

and then I restarted the crond service with `systemctl restart crond` command
but didn't work

It worked when I run this command `cp /etc /backups -R > /dev/n......` in terminal

And my mailx for root is empty.

Could anyone tell me whats wrong with my configuration?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: How often do you think that runs?

Comment: @stark every minute

Comment: I'm not convinced this should have been closed. There are plenty of other [cron] questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/crontab` is not an ordinary crontab file; it's a *system* crontab file. Each line has the usual 5 fields specifying the schedule, then a 6th field specifying the account. With the line you show in `/etc/crontab`, it will attempt to run the command as user `cp`.

If you're using the Vixie cron implementation (you probably are), run `man 5 crontab` and search for "**EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE**".

I recommend not touching `/etc/crontab`. Rather use the `crontab` command to create a user crontab for whichever account you want. Run `crontab` as `root` if the command begin run needs root access.

Comment: Thank you, there are differences between the format of system cron and user cron, I didn't notice that before,thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think now its fine

```
[root@localhost public]# crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
[root@localhost public]# systemctl restart crond
[root@localhost public]# crontab -l
* * * * * cp /etc /backups -R > /dev/null && tar -Jcf /backups/etc-`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d- \%H-\%M-\%S`.tar.xz /backups/etc > /dev/null && rm -rf /backups/etc > /dev/null
[root@localhost public]#
```

Comment: thank you, I get the point of this problem now